# Evaluate $\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{dx}{4+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\dfrac{dx}{4+x^2}$$

**Method $1$:**

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\tan^{-1}\dfrac{2}{2}-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{-2}{2}\right)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

**Method $2$:**

$$x=\dfrac{1}{t}$$
$$dx=\dfrac{-dt}{t^2}$$

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\dfrac{-dt}{4t^2+1}$$

$$-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\tan^{-1}(1)-\tan^{-1}(-1)\right)$$
$$-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Why am I getting different answers through two different methods?

Comment: Mm, the second method seems inapplicable, you have 0 in your interval. If you know the primitive of your function (as in this case), it is better to apply TFC.

Comment: Hi prat! Is there anything that could be improved within the two answers given? If so, feel free to tell us! If not, you could [accept](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) on of the given answers to show that you're satisfied :)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out your substitution went wrong as $0$ is within your domain of integration. Anyway, note that we are dealing with an even function so we can avoid this problem and still apply the subsitution $x\mapsto\frac1x$ and obtain the same result.

On the on hand we have
$$\int_{-2}^2\frac{{\rm d}x}{4+x^2}=2\int_0^2\frac{{\rm d}x}{4+x^2}=2\left[\frac12\arctan\frac x2\right]_0^2=2\left[\frac12\frac\pi4-0\right]=\color{red}{\frac\pi4}$$
And on the other hand
$$\int_{-2}^2\frac{{\rm d}x}{4+x^2}=2\int_0^2\frac{{\rm d}x}{4+x^2}=2\int_\frac12^\infty\frac{{\rm d}x}{1+4x^2}=2\left[\frac12\arctan(2x)\right]_\frac12^\infty=2\left[\frac12\frac\pi2-\frac12\frac\pi4\right]=\color{red}{\frac\pi4}$$

The substitution worked out in this approach as we actually take care of our singularity  in $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to address the seeming disparity between Methods 1 and 2.

Let's break your integral into two pieces to get a better handle of what is going on.

$$\int_{-2}^2 \frac{1}{4+x^2}\,dx = \int_{-2}^{0^-} \frac{1}{4+x^2}\,dx + \int_{0^+}^2 \frac{1}{4+x^2}\,dx.$$

Making the substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$, then $dx = -\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt$. Note now that as $t\to 0^-$, $\frac{1}{t}\to -\infty$ and similarly for $t\to 0^+$ we get $\frac{1}{t}\to +\infty$. This gives us

$$\int_{-2}^2 \frac{1}{4+x^2}\,dx = -\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{4t^2+1}\,dt - \int_{+\infty}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{4t^2+1}\,dt.$$

From here, use a little bit about what you know about $\arctan$ at infinity and you'll see that you get the same result.